# Azure: Federations have been deprecated, so how to implement 'custom sharding'?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sharding, sql-azure-federations

I logged into Azure at the weekend to set up a basic federated database structure, and discovered that Federations have been deprecated.

I contacted Microsoft Customer Support who advised I should implement custom sharding for sclaing the database. However, I can't find any guidance on MS website for recommended approaches to this. The only article i've discovered references custom sharding but doesn't go into detail on how to approach this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495641.aspx.

I'm an Azure newbie, and i'm just looking to set up a basic 4 table relational database, pump a load of data into it and then run queries against the db to look at the performance - if anyone can advise on a suitable approach (a tutorial would be perfect) to custom sharding i'd be hugely grateful.

Appreciate any help anyone can offer.
Regards,
Jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jon,
See a session here - the referenced sample library should be available soon:

SQL Database Sharding Patterns: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/SqlDbShardingIntro

-Simon.

Comment: There is also some earlier material from the same team (AzureCAT) on sharding at: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/09/05/dal-sharding-of-rdbms/

Comment: Simon, Neil - thanks for both of these. The paper's useful to reference against, and i'll find an hour to watch the video content. Many thanks for your very speedy help  :-)   Jon

Comment: MS has just released a utility to migrate away from Federation

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Federations-Migration-ce61e9c1
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Windows-Azure/Azure-SQL-Database-Federations-Migration

Comment: Please also see Elastic Scale for SQL Database: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-documentation-map/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Elastic Database Tools features of Azure SQL DB, which have been released to replace Federations.  A comprehensive set of documentation can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-documentation-map/) along with a 5-minute getting started example [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-get-started/).